# Import from SQL Server folder from previous version

Tags: import, sql-server-2008-r2, upgrade, sql-server-2014

Over the weekend my corporate PC got patched (without warning!) and my instance of SQL Server 2008 R2 was removed leaving behind it's `MSSQL\DATA` folder containing the `.mdf` and `.ldf` files.

I am now installing SQL Server 2014 (we still run Win 7 so cannot go to 2016).

Is it possible to import and upgrade all the old databases into SQL Server 2014?

I am aware that I can attach the existing files but that leaves them in the old `MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER` folder.

Is it simply a case of moving the files to the `MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER` folder, attaching, and then changing the Compatibility Level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to just simply attach the existing `.mdf` files and update the compatibility level and be done with it :-)

Going from an older version of SQL Server (2008 R2 in your case) to a newer one (2014) should never really be a problem (unless you wait *too long* to upgrade - you cannot go from 2000 to 2014 directly anymore).

The other way around never works - you can **never** go from a newer version (e.g. your 2014) back to an older one - there's just simply no way to do this (other than scripting our your database structure and contents into SQL files and running those against the other instance)

Comment: Once I had copied the files to the 2014 DATA folder I had to launch SSMS using an account with admin rights - my normal account is only a Power User and doesn't have permissions to open from the DATA folder